# General confusion about how to start

Tags: ide, esp32

I want to test around with my ESP32 and an E-Paper display - yet i am stuck at uploading sketches via Arduino IDE. I get those kind of errors:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x48
```

and looking into tools,i dont even see my board there - i bought it on amazon and the article just says "ILS - LOLIN32 Lite V1.0.0 Wifi and Bluetooth Board with ESP-32 Rev1 MicroPython 4MB FLASH".

What am i missing here? I am 99% sure i got the pins correct (finally), i got the USB-Serial driver, i got the right port - yet even a simple test sketch i found on the internet didnt work.

Comment: Uh.. have you installed ESP32 support in the Arduino IDE and have the correct board selected? Can you include a screenshot of your Arduino IDE when you try to upload the code?

Comment: what do you mean, "installed ESP32 support"? and i highly doubt i have the correct board selected i tried uploading multiple times on different board - but i dont know how to find out what board exactly i have in the IDE that. here is a screenshot: https://ibb.co/crQQLd

Comment: In the lower right corner you can see you have selected "Arduino Uno" board on COM3 as your target device. That's not what you want. You need to install the ESP32 Core for the Arduino IDE to be able to use the ESP32 boards and select it under `Werkzeuge -> Board`. Try to follow these instructions and check back if it worked: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/docs/arduino-ide/windows.md or https://www.smart-prototyping.com/blog/How%20to%20Install-ESP32-Core-Arduino-IDE

Comment: aah, i never heard of such thing being required to install - i always thought that ESP32 is just a generic name for those dev boards and that arduino boards are ESP32 with different specs. thanks, i will try to get that working for now

Comment: Clarification: "Arduino" is a framework / core. It is a set of functions (like `millis()`, `digitalWrite()`, `digitalRead()`, so to say. There are very different Arduino-Compatible boards (most famous: Arduino Uno / Nano / Mega, ESP8266, ESP32, STM32..). But since these boards are all from entirely different architecture (AVR vs XTensa vs ARM ..), they all need a different **implementation** of the Arduino Core. Thus you need to extend your Arduino IDE with more Cores for different board types to use them with the Arduino Framework.

Comment: Now i understand - i guess its a little like a driver for Arduino running on my LOLIN32?

Comment: alright, everything set up, now it seems to be working (at least more than before) - but i get this error: (it appears twice, the first two words mean "invalid library"):

`Ungültige Bibliothek C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\espressif\esp32\libraries\BLE in C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\espressif\esp32\libraries\BLE gefunden`

Comment: You must execute a recursive git pull in Arduino/hardware/esp32: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/766 . Did you install it by the downloaded ZIP file or via a git pull? Seems like you **need** the git pull, because the github ZIP doesn't contain sub-gits.

Comment: i downloaded the ZIP and i think i got all files i need via the python script that was included - i get a lot more feedback from the IDE now, it seems to be working, after pressing "upload" it ends with "leaving" and "hard resetting via RTS pin" - dont know if thats a good thing yet, i couldnt see any results on the board or on the display yet

Comment: I'd need a full log / screenshot for that. What exact sketch are you running? Can you try running the sketch https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/examples/WiFiScan/WiFiScan.ino and look at the serial monitor at 115200 baud?

Comment: yes! i can see entries using the sketch you provided - i was using a LED  blinking sketch i found online and that did not blink the big blue LED on the board - the next step i want to take is using the example sketch for a 7.5" e-paper display that i got from the arduino folder, but uploading that never did anything even with (i suppose) correct pin mapping

Comment: You should be able to blink the LED if you remove `LED_BUILTIN` for `22` in the example blink sketch (see schematics [here](https://wiki.wemos.cc/products:lolin32:lolin32_lite) and [here](https://wiki.wemos.cc/_media/products:lolin32:sch_lolin32_lite_v1.0.0.pdf). However, connecting an E-Paper display should be posted as a different question with more information (code, wireup, ..).

Comment: i am confused - i used this sketch: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Blink
on my LOLIN32 but i only see a small, red LED blinking - i suppose that is not the right one, and it doesnt blink every 1 second aswell. what is that "`LED_BUILTIN` for `22`" that you are talking about? excuse me if i am overlooking something obvious here

Comment: In the code, `LED_BUILTIN` appears 3 times. Replace every `LED_BUILTIN` by the number `22`. The LED is on pin number 22 as I've shown you in the schematic diagram. Very likely LED_BUILTIN is just wrongly set by default. You're probably seeing that "CHARGE" LED flicker, not the one labeled "22"?

Comment: that might be true, now i understand - the sketch comments say that the LED_BUILTIN is set to the right pin by default - and yes, the 22 fixed it, thanks a lot - now i can finally move to the e-paper after fiddling around for more than a week!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino IDE does not have a core for the ESP32 installed by default.

The problem was solved by explicitly installing the [ESP32-Arduino Core](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32) in the Arduino IDE according to their manuals

- https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/docs/arduino-ide/windows.md
- https://www.smart-prototyping.com/blog/How%20to%20Install-ESP32-Core-Arduino-IDE